# ¿Cómo evitar que contenido <dd> se corte en dispositivos con pantallas pequeñas?

Tags: html, css, responsive

Estoy trabajando con `dl`, `dt` y `dd`, pero tengo un probema con los `dd`, cuando el contenido es más largo que la pantalla éste se corta al final del límite derecho de la pantalla.

¿Cómo podría hacer que se muestre en la línea siguiente?

Este es un trozo del código:

```css
dl {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

dt {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 0 1em 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0em;
  line-height: 10px;
}

dd {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0em 0em 0em 2em;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 0em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <p><strong>I Martes (Impar)</strong></p>
  <dt>– <a href="https://www.deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-01_tiempo-ordinario_dia-03-martes_impar/" target="_blank">Homilías</a></dt>
  <dt><br>–<a href="https://www.deiverbum.org/app/liturgia/misa/lecturas/id/517/" target="_blank"> Lecturas</a></dt>
  <dd><strong>Heb</strong> 2, 5-12: <em>Convenía perfeccionar mediante el sufrimiento al jefe que iba a guiarlos a la salvación</em></dd>
  <dd><strong>Sal</strong> 8, 2ab y 5. 6-7. 8-9: <em>Diste a tu Hijo el mando sobre las obras de tus manos</em></dd>
  <dd><a href="https://www.deiverbum.org/mc-01_21b-28/" target="_blank"><strong>Mc</strong> 1, 21b-28</a>: <em>Les enseñaba con autoridad</em></dd>
</dl>
```

En este caso, esta línea por ejemplo:

**Heb** 2, 5-12: *Convenía perfeccionar mediante el sufrimiento al jefe que iba a guiarlos a la salvación*

Se ve así en una tablet:

**Heb** 2, 5-12: *Convenía perfeccionar mediante el sufrimiento al jefe que*

La parte que seguiría abajo no se ve.

Comment: @Marcos he estado probando varias cosas ... el `line-height: 0em;` lo puse porque cuando lo quito queda demasiado espacio entre los `dd`. Haciendo todo lo que me dices se resuelve, pero ahora los `dd` quedan muy espaciados, ¿cómo podría reducir el espacio entre ellos?

Comment: Puede ser algo como `line-height: 1em;` o `margin-top: -4px;` (_o `margin-bottom`_)...

Comment: @Marcos sigue quedando mucho espacio... ¿Puede que esté habiendo interferencias con otras reglas CSS del sitio?

Comment: Es dificíl para mi decir un número exacto, cuando no puedo ver lo que vos estas viendo, pero la idea sería esa. Tené en cuenta que podes usar decimales, por ejemplo, `line-height: 0.5em;`. Y si, es probable que otras reglas esten afectando tu snippet.

Comment: @Marcos, según las pruebas, tengo que ponerle un valor no menor de `line-height:1em;` si le pongo `line-height:.5em;` se ve bien en el PC, pero no en el móvil, donde el contenido multilinea se muestra encima de la misma línea. Lo dejaré con valor `1em` (aunque se ve demasiado separado para mi gusto en el PC, se ve perfecto en los dispositivos móviles).

Comment: Por las dudas, también podes usar otras unidades, por ejemplo `2ex`. Mas [info acá](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#unidades_de_longitud_relativa)

Comment: @Marcos pasa lo mismo con `ex` (contenido multilínea sobrepuesto en la misma línea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi propuesta sería:

- Sacar a los `dl` la regla:

  - `overflow: hidden;`
- Sacar a los `dd` las reglas:

  - `line-height: 0em;`
  - `white-space: nowrap;`
  - `width: 100%;`

#### Ejemplo :

```css
dl {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

dt {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 0 1em 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0em;
  line-height: 10px;
}

dd {
  padding: 0em 0em 0em 2em;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <p><strong>I Martes (Impar)</strong></p>
  <dt>– <a href="https://www.deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-01_tiempo-ordinario_dia-03-martes_impar/" target="_blank">Homilías</a></dt>
  <dt><br>–<a href="https://www.deiverbum.org/app/liturgia/misa/lecturas/id/517/" target="_blank"> Lecturas</a></dt>
  <dd><strong>Heb</strong> 2, 5-12: <em>Convenía perfeccionar mediante el sufrimiento al jefe que iba a guiarlos a la salvación</em></dd>
  <dd><strong>Sal</strong> 8, 2ab y 5. 6-7. 8-9: <em>Diste a tu Hijo el mando sobre las obras de tus manos</em></dd>
  <dd><a href="https://www.deiverbum.org/mc-01_21b-28/" target="_blank"><strong>Mc</strong> 1, 21b-28</a>: <em>Les enseñaba con autoridad</em></dd>
</dl>
```